# Populating state from localstorage in React

Tags: reactjs

In my react + flux based application, I make a API call to fetch the data in `componentDidMount()` function of React Component. But just to improve the UX, I also query into `localstorage` to see if the UI can be populated from it & accordingly I update the state.

So far, I have been making this call to query into `localstorage` in `componentWillMount()` function, thus avoiding the extra `render()` call due to stateChange.

But while implementing server side render, React throws an error saying "Rendered server side HTML did not match Client side render: Checksum fail". Reason for this error is that, server won't be able to read `localstorage` so would still carry initial state to render. But client can read the `localstorage` & hence the initial render will be different.

So my question to the community is, is there any better way to achieve this? To populate UI using `localstorage` in initial render rather than in 2nd render call & still use server side rendering without causing "Checksum fail" error by react on client?

Comment: why not use  the `getInitialState` entry method for setting your data from the localStorage? It only gets loaded at the start of the component, sets the state and after that you can update settings as you like :)

Comment: Modify your code to check `localStorage` in `componentDidMount` before you make the network call, and only make the network call if you don't have the information locally.

Comment: @Icepickle reading localStorage from `getInitialState` or `componentWillMount` makes sense if your app will be rendered only on client side. If server side rendering is also in place(isomorphism), then one will end up getting React warning of Checksum failure which is what I am getting :)

Comment: @MatthewHerbst Yes, that is what I am doing. But that would cause render function after initial render. And in my case, I always make a API call because localstorage data might be stale & cannot be relied upon. In total, it would cause 3 render calls. I am trying to achieve it in 2 :)

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could provide some sample code, both server and client.

Comment: @JigarJain don't underestimate how fast `render` actually is, as long as your component is a pure (deterministic) rendering of its props/state.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst Yes, I agree & my render is purely based on props/state. But just because something is fast doesn't mean we should over use it :)

Answer (score 0):

> “Premature optimization is the root of all evil”

Now, we could get something working however.

Question is, how to synchronise SSR state and client-side state for the initial render ?

What does the server knows about the client ?

request details, maybe IP, loggedIn status, etc.

I think you should approach this in the same way we approach login: cookies

Cookies allow you to attach a bit of data to every requests the client sends to the server. **Big warning**: if you put too much data you will have network performance issues

You can stringify a Javascript object (JSON) describing every theme options and store that in a cookie.

Then before starting SSR you parse that cookie and use it to initialise your state server-side.

I cannot give you an example since that would require a lot of time, but I think you get the idea.

Good luck